# Is css broken for SFSE?

Tags: support, bug, design

I opened SFSE, and to my surprise, the look and feel seems a bit odd, is CSS broken after recent update? To whom should I report this?

[image]

Comment: Please tag this as a bug so that the developers can check on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Code of Conduct bar just pushes down all the content. Once you close it out the banner returns to normal.